# How to do I get my free Netlify subdomain to connect via CNAME to my domain?

Tags: netlify

I have a free account at Netlify.

I have a domain `tanguay.info` at another provider.

I created a site at Netlify called `dpodreact.netlify.app` and want it to appear when on types `dpodreact.tanguay.info` and so added a CNAME on my site.

[image]

Visiting `dpodreact.tanguay.info` gives an HTTPS error.

How can I connect this CNAME subdomain to my Netlify account without hosting my whole domain at Netlify?

Answer (score 1):

Netlify will only auto-provision a certificate if they are the DNS nameservers being used.
You can get a certificate from elsewhere though, (possibly via your current DNS provider), and click on that "Provide your own certificate" button.